# Using NSFileManager and createDirectoryAtPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to create a new folder, but I can't figure out how to use createDirectoryAtPath correctly.

According to the documentation, this is the correct syntax:

```
NSFileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(_:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:)
```

I tried this:

```
let destinationFolder: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let deliverablePath: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(destinationFolder)/\(arrayOfProjectIDs[index])")!
NSFileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(deliverablePath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
```

But this gives me the error

> Extra argument 'withIntermediateDirectories' in call

I've also tried a lot of variations, removing parameters and so on, but I can't get it to run without an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `defaultManager()` and to convert the NSURL to String.

You can try replacing

`NSFileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(deliverablePath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)`

with this (converting your NSURL to String)

```
var deliverablePathString = deliverablePath.absoluteString

NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(deliverablePathString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you're going to create a URL it makes the most sense to use `createDirectoryForURL`.  Also, if you're passing a URL's path to a function expecting you should use `fileSystemRepresentation`, not `absoluteString`.

Answer (score 10):

The Swift 2.0 way:

```
do {
    var deliverablePathString = "/tmp/asdf"
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(deliverablePathString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`createDirectoryAtPath` expects a `String` for the first parameter, not a URL.  Try passing your path directly or use the URL-friendly variant `createDirectoryForURL`.

Here is an example:

`NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath("/tmp/fnord", withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on seb's code above.
When I used this in my function I had to add a generic catch too.
This removed the "Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive" error.

```
do {
    var deliverablePathString = "/tmp/asdf"
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(deliverablePathString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
} catch {
    print("general error - \(error)", appendNewline: true)
}
```